# If else not working as expected

Tags: java

The "You are normal weight" and "you are over weight" won't display.
My code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BodyMassIndex
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          double bmi, weight, height;

          System.out.println("----LETS CHECK YOUR BMI----");
          System.out.print("Enter your weight (kg): ");
          weight = scan.nextDouble();
          System.out.print("Enter your height (m): ");
          height = scan.nextDouble();
          System.out.println("-----------RESULTS----------");
          bmi = weight/(height*height);
          System.out.printf("%-10s%-4.2f" , "\t\t Your BMI is " , bmi); 
          if(bmi<18.5)
             {System.out.println("\n\t\t You are UNDERWIGHT");}
          else if(bmi==18.5 && bmi <= 24.9)
            {System.out.println(" You are NORMAL WEIGHT");}
          else if(bmi==25 && bmi <= 29.9)
            {System.out.println(" You are OVERWEIGHT");}
          else if(bmi > 30)
            {System.out.println("\n\t\t You are OBESE");}
        else
            {}
        }
      }
```

Comment: change bmi==18.5 to bmi >=18.5 and bmi==25 to bmi >=25

Comment: Just remove the lower values (whatever is before the `&&`), since they're taken care of in the previous `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yossef is correct for the change. However i feel it is important you understand what your logic was doing and why it didn't work.

So let's go ahead and just look at that first else if statement as the same explanation covers both the errors.

else if(bmi==18.5 && bmi <= 24.9)

So here, you're looking for the case where bmi is between 18.5 and 24.9. With the && in the conditional statement, you  are requiring both statements to be true in order for it pass that check (per say) and trigger the print statement.

So let's look at two cases:

1) Bmi = 18.5

```
First, fact check: is bmi between 18.5 and 24.9? Yes.

Now, your code's logic:

       bmi == 18.5? True
       bmi <= 24.9? True
```

Both passed in this case. However, will that work for any number between. 18.5 and 24.9? Let's do one more case

2) Bmi = 20.0

```
First, fact check: is bmi between 18.5 and 24.9? Yes.

Now, your code's logic:

       bmi == 18.5? False
       bmi <= 24.9? True
```

In this case, it fails because bmi is not 18.5. So for any bmi that is not 18.5 but is between 18.5 and 24.9, the check will fail.

Hope that clarified the why!

EDIT:

AntonH made a great point which I failed to leave out.

> You may also want to explain why `bmi <= 24.9` is bad, and `bmi < 25` is better (because the whole thing comes down if bmi == 24.95).

So as he stated, using bmi < 25 allows for your application to correctly evaluate  more precise bmi values (i.e. more decimal points) such as the case AntonH uses where bmi is 24.95.

Comment: You may also want to explain why `bmi <= 24.9` is bad, and `bmi < 25` is better (because the whole thing comes down if bmi == 24.95).

Answer (score 0):

Change the if statement - logic in brackets

```
 bmi==18.5 to bmi >=18.5 and bmi==25 to bmi >=25
```

Answer (score -1):

Your if statements are wrong. Correct it this way:

```
else if(bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9)
        {System.out.println(" You are NORMAL WEIGHT");}
else if(bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9)
        {System.out.println(" You are OVERWEIGHT");}
```